# OpenWRT HTTPS/SSL Traffic Redirect

Tags: ssl, https, router, lighttpd, openwrt

I have the following problem:

I'm running a router with openwrt and a lighttpd webserver and i'm trying to redirect https traffic to a specific domain.

Here is my lighttpd.conf:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
  url.redirect  = (
    "" => "http://name.tld",
  )
}
```

If I call `routerip:443` everything works fine,
but when I call `https://routerip` it gives me an error, for example:

> ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED

or something with DNS_ERROR

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is relying explicitly on the redirect destination, which in your example still uses "http" as the protocol. Try modifying your redirect to include https:

```
url.redirect  = (
  "" => "https://name.tld",
)
```